# How to set root application of IIS to use non-default app pool

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I'm using IIS v7.5. Today I was facing some issues with IIS which took me to make an observation on the app pools. I observed that **DefaultAppPool** has one application assigned to it even though I never run any of my web applications on **DefaultAppPool**. It is shown in the below snapshot:

[image]

On further investigation, I found out that **Root Application** which comes by default with IIS is using it. I want **Root Application** to stop using **DefaulAppPool** and should instead use another app pool named **LocalAppPool**. **LocalAppPool** is a custom app pool that I've created. The problem is **DefaultWebSite** doesn't show any node corresponding to **Root Application** in left navigation pane. So I can't change the app pool it is mapped to by right clicking the web app Node in left pane **>** context menu **>** **Manage Application** menu item **>** **Advanced Settings...** menu item (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Then, app pool can be changed on Advanced Setting pop-up window (Refer screenshot):

[image]

Can someone help me if there is a way to change the app pool assigned to **Root Application** of IIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by selecting the **Default Web Site** itself in IIS and click on **Basic Settings** from **Actions** pane and change the assigned app pool (Refer screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Got it. Only thing is I got it after selecting `Default Web Site` node in left navigation pane. Thanks! Have updated your answer for the same.

Comment: @RBT or we should say the site node in IIS Manager itself also represents the root application.

Comment: True @LexLi. But, I specifically mentioned `Default Web Site` node name as there can be multiple web sites created in IIS in addition to `Default Web Site`. IIS's root application is always associated with `Default Web Site` instead which comes by default when you enable internet information services feature.

Comment: @RBT nope, that's not true. Every web site has its own root application (if you check the configuration file). I guess you might mean something else.